# Print the indices of elements in one list according to the values of another list in seperate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, duplicates

```
A = [['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['a'], ['b']]
B =  [['a'], ['b']]
```

I have two list A and B. I have to print those elements index number(index number+1) of list A ,which elements also exist in list B. For every element of list B, I want to print the indices of the values in list A sequentially in one line. How can i fix this?

**My code:**

```
for i,x in enumerate(A):
    for y in B:
        if x == y:
            print(A.index(x)+1,end=" ")
```

**Output of my code:**

```
1 1 3 1 3
```

**Expected output:**

```
1 2 4
3 5
```

Comment: Your output is correct. All elements of A are in B. `1 2 4` would be wrong

Comment: As mentioned your output is correct.  However, you should replace the inner for loop with `if x in B:` since this is simpler and higher performance.

Comment: @PlabonKumer, `1 2 4` on what logic?

Comment: Thank you all,it's my fault to understand

Comment: @Austin I fixed my question.Can you please check again?

Comment: @CodePope Can you please check again ?

Comment: @DarrylG i fixed my question issue.Can you please check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use dictionaries:

```
A = [['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['a'], ['b']]
B =  [['a'], ['b']]
dict_B = dict([(b[0],[]) for b in B])
for i,a in enumerate(A):
    if a[0] in dict_B:
        dict_B[a[0]].append(i+1)

for key in dict_B:
    print(' '.join(map(str, dict_B[key])))
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 
3 5
```

Another one is to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array(A)
for elem in B:
    item_index = np.where(np_array==elem)
    print(' '.join(map(str, item_index[0]+1)))
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 
3 5
```

Comment: I learnt some new things from this solution. Thank you so much! @Code Pope

Answer (score 2):

The code will go like this to get 1,2,4 as output

```
for i,x in enumerate(A):
    if x==B[0]:
        print(i+1,end=" ")
```